# How to increase compute_budget?

Tags: transactions, compute-budget

I want to increase compute budget, but I got following error message.
How to add compute_budget instruction ?

Rust

```
    let payer = &Keypair::from_base58_string("*******************");
    let rpc = RpcClient::new("https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net".to_string());
    let budget_instr = ComputeBudgetInstruction::set_compute_unit_limit(1_400_000);
    let recent_blockhash = rpc.get_latest_blockhash()?;
    let message = Message::new(&[budget_instr], Some(&payer.pubkey()));
    let txn = Transaction::new(&[payer], message, recent_blockhash);
    let signature = rpc.send_and_confirm_transaction(&txn);
    match signature {
        Ok(sig) => println!("send tx.{:?}", sig),
        Err(err) => println!("error: {:?}", err),
    }
    Ok(())
```

Error message

```
error: ClientError { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError
 { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0:
 invalid instruction data", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult 
{ err: Some(InstructionError(0, InvalidInstructionData)), logs: Some([]), accounts: None,
 units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) }
```

After all, I fixed forcefully like this, refferring someone's tx. it works well.

Rust

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone, BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct ComputeBudgetInstruction {
    buffer: u8,
    limit: u32,
    price: u32,
}

pub fn budget_instruction() -> Instruction {
    let budget_id = Pubkey::from_str("ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111").unwrap();
    let data = ComputeBudgetInstruction {
        buffer: 0,
        limit: 1_400_000,
        price: 1,
    };
    Instruction::new_with_borsh(budget_id, &data, vec![])
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

.....

    let payer = &Keypair::from_base58_string("*******************");
    let rpc = RpcClient::new("https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net".to_string());
    let budget_instr = budget_instruction();
    let main_instr = ......;
    let recent_blockhash = rpc.get_latest_blockhash()?;
    let message = Message::new(&[budget_instr, main_instr], Some(&payer.pubkey()));
    let txn = Transaction::new(&[payer], message, recent_blockhash);
    let signature = rpc.send_and_confirm_transaction(&txn);
    match signature {
        Ok(sig) => println!("send tx.{:?}", sig),
        Err(err) => println!("error: {:?}", err),
    }
    Ok(())
```

solana docs about compute-budget

https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime#compute-budget

Comment: which cluster are you targeting? the feature that enables this instruction may not be activated

Comment: mainnet-beta.
My instruction's compute budget was decreased from 1_400_000 to 200_000 from July 12 and all my instructions failed.

Comment: right. the new compute budget instructions haven't been activated there as they are still under testing on devnet.  in the mean time you can use the deprecated instruction as referenced [below](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/132/36)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using this inplace of set_compute_limit
`ComputeBudgetInstruction::RequestUnitsDeprecated(1_400_000u32);`

Comment: Does this require extra payment?

Comment: Thank you Nabeel,
but it does not work in my enviroment.
I fixed forcefully like above for now.

Comment: curious, if you use the solana sdk in ur rust client , https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/src/compute_budget.rs
and use one of the instruction helpers and see if this works, ideally this is how it should work.
not sure what version is being used on mainnet tbh, which version of the api is valid, request_units | request_units_deprecated | set_compute_units